# Linux compatible motherboard

Tags: linux, hardware

Where can I find a list with Linux compatible motherboards.

I want all features of the motherboard to work reasonably well with latest valilla Linux kernel (ie, clearly document that I need external module, and I'll decide if this module is reasonably maintained). Obviously hibernate audio and networking should work.

It is important for me that it would work "out of the box", so that maintaining a few Linux boxes with this motherboard will be easy (recompiling an external kernel module from source for each major kernel upgrade is not that easy...).

Comment: All of them. I haven't found one yet that didn't work.

Comment: @Keith, I recall complaints about hibernation, and on-board graphic chip. Some complaint about very new SATA. But you might be correct, and I might be over-paranoid.

Comment: Well, with one caveat, the ones I use are good quality. Cheap boards may give you trouble, but that's not the fault of Linux.

Comment: By and large, all of them is correct.  There is the occasional board with fubar bios, but you're not going to find a comprehensive list anywhere.  Best thing to do is pick a board and before you buy it, do some googling to see if anyone has complained about linux issues with it.

Comment: I would agree with @Keith; I've been using Linux for well over a decade, and in the last 7-8 years, the only systems I've had an issue with are those with bleeding edge hardware. For example, if the latest chipset was just released, and you get the board the first week it's available, there may be minor issues since on e of the devs haven't gotten their hands on that hardware yet. Buy a board that's a 6-12 month old model, with an Intel or AMD chipset, and chances are you'll be fine (Note: I've NEVER had an issue with ANY Intel hardware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel motherboards has a very good support. They have various developers working in the kernel and xorg.

Look at http://www.linux-drivers.org/. It's a amazing resource for check hardware compatibility.